# System Moniter is not showing CPU History, Network History after installing Steam?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, system-monitoring

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. After installing Steam and Played some games, I found that in System Monitor CPU History & Network history is not showing. I haven't changed any system settings.

How to resolve the issues without unistalling the Steam?

[image: CPU History & Network History is not showing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got help from another forum. It was a known bug in KDE. 
[Known KDE bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224215&fbclid=IwAR12BDX-tUBvj97dXiyUURn1wjP4PMp3nhqQ7pfEXwQHTDSEPzKKdZxoOOc). To solve the issue copy the default “SystemLoad2.sgrd” file from /usr/share/ksysguard/ to ~/.local/share/ksysguard/.